# how do i enter a var in a wordpress custom query?

Tags: wordpress

how do I put a custom var in the following line of the below

```
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'email'
```

I want to put in a var for 'email'

something like

```
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = $var
```

anyone know how to do this is Wordpress. I think i need to bind?

re: http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done that using custom query plugin [Go here](http://www.dailyblogtips.com/best-wordpress-plugins-custom-query-string/)

else custom your query like this

```
<?php

    $args = array('post_type' => 'page','meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'email','value' => 'yes','compare' => '%')));


$var = new WP_Query($args); 

// The Loop

while ( $var->have_posts() ) : $var->the_post();

$P_ID = get_the_ID();



endwhile;



// Reset Post Data

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: in the first query of http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query  i want to add the values from variables, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on context, but if you *really* are performing a custom query (as, say, part of a widget) you would provide it as an argument to [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_value' => 'user@example.com' ) );
```

Oftentimes this would include a corresponding `meta_key` in that argument array.

If you want to modify the currently running query (say, on a category page, only show posts that match a certain criteria) you would perform that modification during the `pre_get_posts` action. Recommended reading: Andrew Nacin's [You Don't Know Query](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-portland-2011).

Comment: how would i do this for the query in the first example? I want the following value to be dynamic ------- AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'email'  --------- something like AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = $var

Comment: in the first query of http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query  i want to add the values from variables, how do i do that?